# RCA Tablet Root problems!

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, linux, tablet

I have an RCA Tablet with Android 6.0.1 and no matter what I try I cannot unlock my root bootloader. When I reboot into the bootloader it just takes me to the main tablet stuff. In other words the screen with the laying down Android robot will not come up. I've used adb and fastboot but the fastboot wont recognize my tablet and adb does. I've tried a lot of one click rooters, and nothing!

Is there any way I can manually re-root my RCA Tablet through the terminal or maybe even get the fastboot to work?

UPDATE: Can you tell me how to install SU binary on to my tablet?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help or not but on my RCA Galileo running 6.0 in the Developer options menu there is switch called "OEM unlocking". That should allow you to unlock the bootloader. I haven't actually tried it so I don't know for sure.

Comment: @bashBedlam Thank you very much, but I have been able to unlock OEM and it didn't really do anything. I have the voyager 3 but its running Android 6.0

Comment: Depending on what RCA tablet model you have, the answer will be the same; try googling: **How to Install CWM/TWRP on your RCA tablet model**. Follow chat for more comments [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86598/discussion-on-answer-by-abdelhafid-madoui-rca-tablet-root-problems). [Edited by Moderator Firelord]

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible, yet. I also have the Voyager III, and there is no way to root this device right now.